# Access data from one system to antother system

Tags: http, networking, dns

i'm accessing a file from one system to another system using IP address bcoz those systems are in local network.
I used this way "http://192.168.0.155:8080/files/index.jsp".but i want access the following way "http://nets:8080/files" like this way. how to possible to access the data this way?

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1:

Add a mapping in your /etc/hosts file that maps `nets` to the ip address `192.168.0.155`

### Method 2:

Ask your system administrator to setup a dns server that does this for you.